# Empty emailsenddefinition in _job, how to find Sender Profile for email already sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to see what Sender Profile for an email that was sent last month. However when I query _job the emailsenddefinition is empty as is the FromName and the FromEmail. Anyone has an idea why it's empty?
And how to get the Sender Profile? I suspect it has something to do with that we use a dynamic sender profile but don't understand why the name of it would be empty.

[image]